# Default value for a variable in a class

Tags: python

I need to parse the environment value from a config file or from os environments in a class.

I am looking for a way to have a default for the `env` variable in case the environment is not found in neither the os.environ nor in the parsed config file.

I have done this: but I am not sure it is the right place? is the `__init__` the right place to define those variables? that are to be re-used later on to establish db connections?

```
import yaml
import os
from socket import gethostname

class wrapper(object):
    with open('config') as fd:
         config = yaml.safe_load(fd)
    hostname = gethostname()    

    def __init__(self, env='prod'):

        self.db_server = None
        self.db_default_user = None

        self.db_connection = None

        for envmt,data in self.config.items():
            if self.hostname in data.get('host'):
                env = envmt

        #override by environment variable
        if 'CMS_ENV' in os.environ:
            env = os.environ['CMS_ENV']


        # Might be overwritten by ENV variables
        db_default_user = self.config[env]['db_default_user']



        db_server = self.config[env]['db_server']

     def db_conn(self):
        user = self.db_default_user
```

the question is how to define a default value to env to fallback to 'prod'?  should this defined at class level or while initializing the instance.

the variable dev is used to get the right db_server and correct user_name to connect and fetch data from a mssql db I must make sure it is defined.

this is the content of the config file:

```
test:
    hosts: [vmtest,vmtest2]
    db_server: cmreplsta01.netdev.deutsche-boerse.de
    db_default_user: example\DB-user
prod:
    hosts: [vmprod,vmprod2]
    db_server: cmsdb.io.deutsche-boerse.de
    db_default_user: example\DB-userprod
```

I detect the hostname where the script runs the load the db_server and db_default_user accordingly. if the script is running from a host not in the config then i default the env to 'prod' an use the prod values.

i have not been able to find any similar question that would fit my use case.

Comment: can you fix the indentation of your code?

Comment: I don't know if the dependencies are hard for you. But a library like (https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) allows you to the same.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a dictionary to store the defaults, then update the values from the environment?

Something like:

```py
import os
defaults = {'EDITOR': 'nano'}
defaults.update(...) # e.g. your config file
defaults.update(os.environ)
```

### Edit

If you don't want to clutter up your `defaults` variable with all the system environment variables, you can filter it to only contain the variables which are common between the original defaults and the environment:

```py
import os
defaults = {'EDITOR': 'nano'}
common_variables = os.environ & env.keys() # set intersection
filtered_env = {k:os.environ[k] for k in common_variables}
defaults.update(filtered_env)
```

Comment: won't this put all of environ keys in your `defaults` dict?

Comment: Yes, it will. I guess they could use a subset of `os.environ` if they don't want that.

Comment: Updated with a version which only includes environment variables which are already specified in `defaults`.

Comment: as you can see in the code the env is auto-detected based on hostname and it can be overriden by os environment. the question is how to make sure the env is set to prod if and only if the script is run from an unknown host (host is in config file) AND is also not defined as a os environment.

Comment: The principle behind this answer e is that you start by setting the default value. i.e. `defaults = {'env': 'prod'}`. Then you update the defaults with the values from the config file, and finally with the values from the os environment. If the environment is defined in either of the latter, it will overwrite the initial default value. If it is not defined, it will not be overwritten, and you will be left with the initial default. This allows your code to always be the same. Just read the value of 'env' from the dictionary.

Comment: I added the contents of config. 
where would the default be defined? outside of the class or inside the `__init__`?

Comment: It probably depends on whether you need to use the default in any other code. If it's *only* for this class, then you could define it at the start of the class (before `__init__`). Otherwise, you could define it globally.